# Problem: Accessing Vector Inside a Thread

Tags: c++

I got a link error when I tried to access vector outside my thread. My design is, when I get a message from a client, I want the massage or data to be in my data queue for further operation. But I can't get them work. Here is my codes:

.cpp file:

```
// Inside the recv thread
start:
    err = recvfrom(RecvSocket, lpData->RecvBuf, BufLen, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&lpData->SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize);
    //lpData is used to access Recv Structure which stores the attributes of the server and client.

    switch(lpData->port)
    {
        case 6516:
        {
            BuffStack1.push_back(lpData->RecvBuf);
            break;
        }

        case 6517:
        {   
            break;
        }

        case 6518:
        {
            break;
        }
    }

goto start;
```

.h file:

```
class CUdpSocket
{
public:
    CUdpSocket(void);
    ~CUdpSocket(void);
    void ServerRecv(int port);
    void ClientSend(const char *ip, int port, const char *buff);
    unsigned static __stdcall ServerRecvThread(void *arguments);
    unsigned static __stdcall ClientSendThread(void *arguments);
    CString static Itoa(int data);
    void Mix();

private:
    RecvStruct *pRecvData;
    SendStruct *pSendData;
    vector<HANDLE>threadStl;
    static vector<char*>BuffStack1;  // Here is my stack vector
    static vector<char*>BuffStack2;
    static vector<char*>BuffStack3;
    HANDLE hThread;
    unsigned threadID;
    static BufferData *ptrBufferData;
};
```

I am a bit confused whether I need to put static or not. And when I put static, the error will be:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::vector<char *,class std::allocator<char *> > CUdpSocket::BuffStack1" (?BuffStack1@CUdpSocket@@0V?$vector@PADV?$allocator@PAD@std@@@std@@A)
```

And if I didn't put static statement, the error says:

```
error C2228: left of '.push_back' must have class/struct/union
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is that in C++, using `static` data members in a class is a two-step process.  First, you need to *declare* the `static` variable, indicating that it has a name and type, and then you must *define* the `static` variable to give it storage space in one of the translation units.  My guess is that you have done that first step but not the second.

To define a `static` variable, put a definition like this one into the .cpp file:

```
vector<char*> CUdpSocket::BuffStack1;
```

Note that you do **not** repeat the `static` keyword here.  Instead, you just give the type and fully-qualified name of the `static` data member.  If you want to use a non-default constructor for the `static` data member, you can do so here as well.

Hope this helps!

PS. Please don't use labels and `goto`s to implement your loop... use a `while(true)` loop instead! :-)

**EDIT:** If you're going to be accessing these `vector`s from the thread, make sure you have some appropriate synchronization in place.  It is not safe to read and write a `vector` from multiple threads without ensuring at the most one thread can modify it at any one time.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What error are you getting?  What in particular isn't working?